# Understand backend in QtService

Tags: qt, ubuntu, qt5, daemon

I wrote a daemon using [Skycoder42/QtService](https://github.com/Skycoder42/QtService).
It works when run from QtCteator but on the server, I get the below error

```
qtservice: No backend found for the name "standard"
```

In the project document, I can't find anything

what is the backend? How can I install the service and start it?

Comment: It would be recommended that you create an issue where you ask the author for an explanation in addition to pointing out the error you get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I find the solution:

We must copy the `path/to/qt/gcc_64/plugins/servicebackends` directory next to executable